# AFrame: How to update schema data on System?

Tags: aframe

Systems in AFrame can declare a [schema](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/core/systems.html) and store data within their `data` object field. However, setting a field on `data` directly does not trigger the `update()` lifecycle handler on the system. What's the correct way to update a system's data and trigger the `update` handler?

For components in AFrame, you can do `element.setAttribute(component, field, value)` to update the data and automatically call the update handler. Is there something like this for systems? I don't believe systems are stored as HTML elements, so I know setAttribute wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AFrame's `a-scene` element overrides `setAttribute` to try and update some data on a system first.

Here's the relevant function pulled from AFrame's `a-scene.js` file:

```js
  /**
   * Wrap Entity.setAttribute to take into account for systems.
   * If system exists, then skip component initialization checks and do a normal
   * setAttribute.
   */
  setAttribute (attr, value, componentPropValue) {
    var system = this.systems[attr];
    if (system) {
      ANode.prototype.setAttribute.call(this, attr, value);
      system.updateProperties(value);
      return;
    }
    AEntity.prototype.setAttribute.call(this, attr, value, componentPropValue);
  }
```